# How to save a text from a UIAlertController

Tags: swift

I want to save the data from whatever is being typed from the text to be saved when you press the save button. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func buttonTappedToSetAReminder(sender: AnyObject) {

     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Reminders", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

     let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
          alert -> Void in

          _ = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField

     })

     let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
          (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

     })

     alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
          textField.placeholder = "Put a reminder!!!"
     }

     alertController.addAction(saveAction)
     alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

     self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: How do you want to save this text? Or you just can't retrieve it from action controller?

Comment: Where do you want to save the data? To a property in the class? On disk?

Comment: You need to get familiar with Xcode's "Documentation and API Reference" under "Help". Look up UITextFieldDelegate and you'll find your answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Within your save action handler, you want to get

- the **textField** from the alertView
- then the **text** from the textField

### Example

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Reminders", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

 let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { action in
     if let textField = alert.textFields?[0], text = textField.text {
         // Do something with text
     } else {
         // Didn't get text
     }
 }

 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
// do something with textField.text
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `NSUserDefaults`/`UserDefaults` is an option:

Swift 2:

```
let textField = alertController.textFields![0]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(textField.text, forKey: "text")
```

Swift 3:

```
let textField = alertController.textFields![0]
UserDefaults.standard.set(textField.text, forKey("text")
```